# how do I prove forall P Q : Prop, ((((P -> Q) -> P) -> P) -> Q) ->Q. in coq?

Tags: coq

I am very new to coq so if you only say intros. I don't know what to introduce. So being specific like (Ex. intros p q.) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, your goal can be automatically solved by the `auto` tactic.
If you use its variant `info_auto`, Coq tells you which steps lead to the solution .

```
Goal  forall P Q : Prop, ((((P -> Q) -> P) -> P) -> Q) -> Q.
  info_auto.
```

Then, you may replay the proof by yourself, and add comments and explicit variables names to the `intros`tactics, and you will understand the
strategy used by `auto` (what to do when the conclusion is a `forall` or an implication, or an atomic proposition).

```
 Restart. 
  intros P Q H.
  apply H (* no-choice ! *).
  intro H0.         
  apply H0.  (* no other possibility ! *)
  intro p. 
  apply H. (* no alternative ! *)
  intros _. 
  assumption. 
Qed.
```

Comment: Some how I can't upvote your comment, but I thank you.